# AlCl3 stuck to Pyrex

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I made $\ce{AlCl3 . 6 H2O}$ the easy way, with $\ce{HCl}$ and foil. After filtering and reducing on the stove, I get a nice yellow crystal of contaminated $\ce{AlCl3 . 6 H2O}$. The yellow should be from $\ce{Fe}$ contamination.

The problem: it is stuck insanely hard to my old Pyrex pan and I’m having trouble getting it out. I can re-dissolve it in water, but that’s a step back. Would nonstick work? Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What's "reducing on the stove"?

Comment: Heating it up to remove the water.

Comment: Then you don't have any AlCl3 anymore.

Comment: Aluminum oxide is insoluble in water. These crystals re-dissolve. I think I still have AlCl3 my only problem is scraping it off the bottom. I specifically used very gentle heat to prevent the oxide from forming.

Comment: To clarify I am not trying to remove the hexahydrate. Only the excess water.

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Heating $\ce{AlCl3·xH2O}$ will never produce anhydrous $\ce{AlCl3}$. Never ! Hydrolysis will always occur, yielding $\ce{AlCl_{3-x}OH_x}$ plus some $\ce{HCl}$

Comment: The «easy way» is $\ce{2Al + 3Cl2 -> 2AlCl3}$ in a flow reactor, but not in a beaker.  An aqueous solution of $\ce{AlCl3}$, stabilized by hydrochloric acid, still will not  provide you an access to *water free* $\ce{AlCl3}$. You likely got something in the range between $\ce{AlOH3}$ (one can dissolve in either acid, or lye) and $\ce{Al2O3}$ because $\ce{Cl^-}$ and $\ce{H+}$ of water became $\ce{HCl}$ and left the container (you mention heating, the escape is more likely then).  Not necessarily [corundum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corundum) (one form of $\ce{Al2O3}$) though.

Comment: I would use polymer Petri dish (easier to scrape off) and vacuum evaporation instead of stove to reduce hydrolysis.